# Today Stock Price is 15. Find value of Call Option

Tags: stocks, options, risk

Stock price is $15 today. In a year, it has 50%-50% chances of going up or down. If it goes up, then 80% probability of the price being $25. If it goes down, then there is a 40% probability of price being $5 and a 60% probability of it being $0. Find the price of a call option at strike $25.

---

My approach:

I think I should, first of all, find the value of the stock on the up branch of the tree that happens with a probability of 0.2. I don't know though how to find such value.

I thought to include in the reasoning the formulas of $p,u,d$ of the tree, but it doesn't seem to help.

This is the tree I am talking about. Nevertheless, in this problem, the tree should have only one node so $n=1$,  and since the maturity is 1 year, t should also be 1, $t=1$

Comment: Your question is?

Comment: the "20%" case should be given to you - without it, there's not an answer. It's a big difference between the stock having a 20% change of being $15.01 and a 20% chance of being $100.

Comment: You also need an interest rate, or discount factor of some sort.

Comment: And, in the end, the value of the option is completely dependent on that value, since in the other three cases the option will be worthless.

Comment: The options prices are given mostly by volatility and the real market - it "feels it". But if you want to calculate a theoretical value of the option with parameters given from your perspective, try a simplified formula like this one here: https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/97534/how-to-calculate-black-scholes-using-google-sheets?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

If this is a theoretical homework problem then I have no clue what the answer is. In the real world, option pricing is based on six option pricing variables:

- stock price
- strike price
- time remaining until expiration
- dividend, if any
- carry cost
- volatility

In your example, the first five are known values today. Volatility is the wild card.  Without it, you can't accurately price the option using an option pricing model to calculate fair value.

Comment: There are binomial option models that don't require an explicit "volatility" input, but model "volatility" as a discrete set of possible outputs and probabilities. The problem is that the question is missing one of those possible outcomes (the "20%" case if the stock goes up).

Comment: Pardon my skepticism but IMO, that's all guesswork since the answer is based on the probability which in itself, is just another guess.

Comment: You're right, and it's a purely academic exercise - in practice a singular vol is much more common, although there are binomial models that use different vols along the lattice based on time/moneyness.

Comment: Although one could argue that even a single implied vol is purely a guess (but a guess based on market sentiment)

Comment: Such theoreticals are above my pay grade.  I suppose that they're useful for examinations but in my world, they don't contribute to any kind of a trading edge.  As for the implied volatility, it's not a guess.  It's an iterated derivative of option price.  You could argue that option price is a function of sentiment but that's getting a bit far afield from from the meaning of implied volatility.

Comment: Implied vol is just a convenient way of describing the price of a specific option, and then extrapolating to other options where you may not have market quotes (or to more complex derivatives).

Comment: Saying that 'Implied vol is just a convenient way of describing the price of a specific option' is a bit of an oversimplification because it also reflects the other 5 pricing variables and thereby  lacks context.